# F# | How to manage WebSocketClient ReceiveAsync on multithread scenario?

Tags: websocket, f#

Looking for WebSocketClient example I only found simple example with a single request/response scenario.

Kind of:

```ml
type WSClientSimple (url) =
    
    let ws = new ClientWebSocket()     
    let lockConnection = Object()

    let connect() =
        lock lockConnection ( fun () ->
            if not (ws.State = WebSocketState.Open) then
                ws.ConnectAsync(Uri(url), CancellationToken.None) 
                |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously // await
            else ()
        ) 

    let receive () =  
        lock lockConnection ( fun () ->
            let rec readStream finalText endOfMessage =
                let buffer = ArraySegment(Array.zeroCreate<byte> 1024)
                let result = ws.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously

                let text = finalText + Encoding.UTF8.GetString (buffer.Array |> Array.take result.Count)
                if result.EndOfMessage then text
                else readStream text true
            readStream "" false
        )

    let sendRequest jsonMessage =
        let bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonMessage:string)
        let bytesMessage = ArraySegment(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

        if not (ws.State = WebSocketState.Open) then
            connect()
        // send request...
        ws.SendAsync(bytesMessage, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
        // ... read response
        receive()

    member this.SendRequest request = sendRequest request
```

Obviously it works with:

```ml
    [<Test>]
    member this.``Receive sequentially`` () =       
        let client = WSClientSimple("url")    
        for i in 1..100 do
            client.SendRequest "aaa" |> ignore
```

and also (thanks to the orrible lock) with multiple thread using the same Client:

```ml
    [<Test>]
    member this.``Receive parallel on same client`` () =  
        let client = WSClientSimple("url")    
        for _ in 1..100 do
            async { 
                client.SendRequest "aaa" |> ignore
            } |> Async.Start
```

Now, if I really want to get the beast from WebSocket "duplex" cpmmunication I would continuosly read from the socket, send requests without any block, and distribute the received messages to the right call.

So, this is an ongoing **receive** function that collect all the inbound messages.

```ml
type WSClientTest2 (url:string) =
    
    let onMessageReceived = new Event<string>()
    let responseMessage = new Event<ResponseMessage>()    

    let receivedMesasages = System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue<ResponseMessage>()
    let responseCallbacks = Map.empty<int, (string -> unit)>
    
    let manageMessage (message:string) =
        match message.Split(':') with 
        | [|id;message|] ->
            responseMessage.Trigger {Id=int(id);Message=message}
            receivedMesasages.Enqueue {Id=int(id);Message=message}
        | _ -> ()

    let startReceiving() =         
        let mutable counter = 1
        async {
            // simulate receiving from a WebSocket 
            while true do  
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay 100 |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously
                onMessageReceived.Trigger (sprintf "message %d" counter)
                manageMessage (sprintf "%d:message" counter)                 
                counter <- counter + 1
        } |> Async.Start
    
    do
        startReceiving()
```

**How can I send a request and wait for the correlated response message?**

This is my try:

```ml
    let mutable requestId = 0
    let sendRequest message: string =

        let requestId = requestId+1

        let received = new Event<string>()
        let receivedCall = fun (msg:string) -> 
            received.Trigger msg

        responseCallbacks.Add(requestId, receivedCall) |> ignore

        let cancel = fun () -> failwith "Timeout"
        async { 
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep 500  // wait x seconds
            cancel()
        } |> Async.Start

        // simulate send/receive messsage after some time   
        let generateRequest () =
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep 100  // wait x time for the response
            responseMessage.Trigger {Id=requestId; Message=message}

        generateRequest()

        Async.AwaitEvent(received.Publish, cancel)
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

*Async.AwaitWaitHandle* seems the right thing to use but I don't know how to create a *WaitHandle*.

I'm using *Async.AwaitEvent* but it seems not to work.
The *cancel()* is always called but it does not raise any Exception!

**What could be a proper way to wait for an Event while executing a function and then check and return its content?**

I also tried to use a Map<id, response> populatd with any inbound message but still I don't know how to "wait" for the proper message and also it probably requires a check for orphan response messages (add complexity).
More in general, if the resulting code is so crappy I would prefer to use a simple API for this Request/Response scenario and use the WebSocket only for a realtime update.
I'm looking for a nice solution, otherwise I think it is not really worth for the sake of performance, not for my needs.

Comment: this might be a bit late but might be useful to you.Currently working/learning websockets and used CE from the Ply library.not only is this faster than bcl tasks it also has the ability to return values from a completed CE. Not sure if this fits your needs but it helped me out. Otherwise mailboxprocessors, but that might be a bit much.